# general advice for existence claims

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-writing

I’m pretty new to proof—based mathematics and have decided to take up reading Linear Algebra Done Right, by Sheldon Axler. So far I’ve noticed that one type of proof I seem to struggle the most with is proving an existence claim. Particularly, showing the existence of some object with a specified property. From what I gather looking at solutions, this process involves defining some object in a clever way that guarantees its existence and allows you to derive the desired property from its definition. But I feel like I have no idea how to carry out that process systematically. Any advice?

For reference here is an example of the kind of problem I’ve struggled with:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

As with all proof-writing, there's no one-size-fits-all approach that will always work— different problems call for different approaches, and with experience you'll build intuition for when a certain approach is suitable. But when trying to show a certain object exists, it's often helpful by *assuming* that object exists, and then figuring out what must be true about it. With luck, you might be able to uniquely characterize that object, and then prove that the object you've constructed satisfies the requirements of the problem.

For instance, let's look at your problem 5. Suppose that $\{v_1,...,v_m\}$ is a basis of the required form. Then we can write $$T(v_i) = \sum_{j=1}^n M_{ji}w_j $$ where the $M_{ij}$ are the matrix entries of $\mathcal{M}(T)$. So, what can we say about the $T(v_i)$ if the problem conditions hold?

Comment: Another absurd closure by stackexchange. Unfortunately, this seems to just not be a good website for pedagogy. Feel free to comment if you'd like further advice; I should be around later tonight.